# Javascript , getting the default page name not shown in the browser URL

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a URL in entered without a filename at the end say "www.google.com" the server actually serves "www.google.com/index.html" or say "www.google.com/default.aspx" or something similar Now given that the browser URL is "www.google.com". I want to get this information )index.html/default.aspx etc) from JavaScript . `window.location` methods which I am aware of gives just domain name and for special URLs like those I mentioned  `location.hostname` returns just "/" but not the filename.

All help is appreciated !.

Thanks.
Mohan

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible. The server does not send a redirect. Besides that, it is pretty possible that there isn't even a physical file that directly corresponds to a given URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible with JavaScript since it defined in the web server configuration

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried location.href yet?